# Adding a base OBS file in RTKLIB post processing program

Tags: rtklib

Why I can not add base OBS file in RTKLIB post processing program?
it is gray?

RTKLIB_bin-rtklib_2.4.3 (Win10)

[image]

Comment: Are the options set for a relative positioning mode that uses a base station?  See http://www.rtklib.com/prog/manual_2.4.2.pdf page 29

Comment: Ohh this was the problem
so I set to kinematic and problem is solved
thank you

Answer (score 1):

**My abve question was answered by the above comment from Dave X**

In *Setting1* tab set *Positioning Mode* to *kinematic*

Also in *Positions* tab set *Base Station* to *Rinex Header Position*

Answer (score 0):

try the new version rtkpost ver.demo5 b34g

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).